# Azure AD users to SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, azure-ad

Need to get Users from Azure AD and update to SharePoint as List with user properties. We're using SharePoint Online.

Is it possible to get all users from Azure AD and update those users to SharePoint as List?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I understood your requirement, you want to fetch all users and their properties and store it into the SharePoint Online List.

If this is correct, then very much this is possible.

You can use [Microsoft Graph API](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users) for fetching the information from AAD.

The request will be like

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

It will give you all users along with the properties information in JSON format.

You have to take care for authentication part. For more information regarding how to authenticate Microsoft Graph API, you can read [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview). Follow each topic under this section and you will be able to get the authentication token.

Let me  know if you need some more information. I recently done this so I am sure that it works.....

Comment: I need to do something similar to embed a phone directory within a page on a Sharepoint Online modern site - just to be clear, is the solution to create a Sharepoint Framework Web part that does Microsoft Graph API requests to update a Sharepoint List? Or is there an easier method? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Aakash Maurya. Could you please share any brief document/blog on this? Is this done by Coding? I'm basically from SharePoint Admin. I do not have coding experience. But i have to perform this activity in my organization.